# What all can make file invisible under windows

Tags: windows-7

Recently, I've installed an alarm application, Citrus Alarm Clock. Since it has a bit awkward alarm managmenent and I needed to clone some settings, I began to seek where the settings are actually saved.

First thing I did was that I looked in documents, then appData and finally in the application installation folder under program files.

No `.cfg`, `.ini` or `.xml` file was found. Well, no suprise, I started searching through registry. Another failure made me really angry, so I downloaded [proccess monitor by microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and tried to see what happens when I change the settings.

This made me discover, that the file is under program files:
[image: screenshot from procmon]

Well, but I've looked here before, and even after - and the folder looks like this:
[image: The file cannot be seen in program files]

I have disabled any file hiding features under windows folder settings.

I believe this has something to do with the fact, that program files is a folder, that is readonly for non administrator accounts.

Comment: the virtualstore is a feature of the UAC (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.uac.aspx) to prevent crashes when old legacy apps try to write to a folder where you don't have write permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: skip to end.

## Background and Technical Explanation

### Problem

Microsoft drastically re-architectured Windows Vista to increase security. One thing they did to increase security was exactly what you said: they restricted access to the `Program Files` folder.

This isn’t a problem for most programs because they don’t normally write to their installation directory after they are installed, but some programs are poorly designed (or really old) and write user settings and such to the program directory instead of to the user folder.

### Solution

To provide backward compatibility with these kinds of programs, Microsoft created a virtualized environment. What happens is that when a non-admin user runs a program that tries to read or write to the installation directory, instead of directly accessing the file-system, they access it through a shim which intercepts such file operation requests and redirects them to a directory in the user folder as necessary. This way, no user can corrupt the program itself (or any other program).

### Examples

This is common with old programs, including programs that are still being developed but have been around for a while. For example, IrfanView is still actively developed, but because it started out a long time ago with an older version of Windows, it still writes its settings to the installation folder and thus gets redirected to the virtual store. Also, old games (e.g., Quake 3, Serious Sam, etc.) are *often* subject to redirection because they frequently stored settings, saved games, and screenshots in the program folder instead of the user document folder.

In addition, some old programs write to the Windows directory, so Windows virtualizes that as well. It seems crazy now, but in days long past, before Windows 95 introduced the registry, most programs actually stored their settings in `\windows\win.ini`. Such venerable programs (assuming they can even run on a Windows 7 system) will have their file operations redirected to the virtual store, to their own, personal copy of `\windows\win.ini` or `\windows\system32\unwise.log`, and so on.

### Location

Windows keeps a separate virtual store for each user (which has the benefit of allowing per-user settings, saved games, etc. even for programs that didn’t natively support that). You can see the virtual store at `%localappdata%\VirtualStore`.

## Summary/Application

In your case, Citrus Alarm Clock is such a program and so Windows redirects any configuration files it tries to write to the virtual store at `%localappdata%\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Citrus Alarm Clock`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in your first screenshot.

Citrusad.exe createfile c:\program files (x86)\Citrus Alarm Clock\settings.xml  ***REPARSE***

> Reparse Point - A file or directory can contain a reparse point, which
>   is a collection of user-defined data. The format of this data is
>   understood by the application which stores the data, and a file system
>   filter, which you install to interpret the data and process the file.
>   When an application sets a reparse point, it stores this data, plus a
>   reparse tag, which uniquely identifies the data it is storing. When
>   the file system opens a file with a reparse point, it attempts to find
>   the file system filter associated with the data format identified by
>   the reparse tag. If a file system filter is found, the filter
>   processes the file as directed by the reparse data. If a file system
>   filter is not found, the file open operation fails.

So in other words, the file is actually being saved somewhere else.

You can see the file's true location on the next line:

c:\users\jakub\appdata\local\virtualstore\program files (x86)\citrus alarm clock\settings.xml

Comment: I think the actual path is given on the next line of process monitor.

Comment: good catch.  didnt see that.  Theres your answer.